# M-PLUS and HLM 7 for Hierarchical Linear Modeling

Tags: multilevel-analysis, mplus

Many of my colleagues are considering using the M-PLUS package to carry out Hierarchical Linear Modeling, rather than the HLM 7 package.  Both packages are designed by very well respected figures in the field of Hierachical Linear Modeling.  Have any users seen distinct statistical advantages in using one package or the other?

Comment: Please don't sign off on your posts, I recognize (& applaud) the urge to be polite, but your avatar & username is already added automatically. Moreover, it's contrary to SE's policy.

Comment: Don't both of those cost a lot of money? R is free, & not too difficult to learn.

Comment: @gung - thanks for the heads up on signing posts.  Henceforth, my avatar will speak for me. HLM and MPlus cost close to $1,000.  Great packages, but i will check out R.

Comment: No problem. If you want advice on learning R, or using it for specific applications (eg, multi-level modeling), be sure to ask here, or on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). There are a lot of great tutorials / resources available free online, & sometimes a quick answer will help you keep going. Trying to learn R from scratch on your own, w/o a sense of how & where to start, can be very frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to agree with the previous post, R is a good alternative to these. I've used both HLM and M-PLUS and find that data manipulation is difficult to impossible, and the scripting language of R is much better for actually using the results from the models.
my 2 cents.